# DB error: No such field (Civi 4.7.15)

Tags: database, payment-processor

I've gotten No such field errors for no apparent reason since my first Civi installation, but one that I haven't been able to shake is preventing creation of any payment processors. It looks like this:

On the Add Payment Processor form, I submit the completed form and this appears ...

```
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: no such field"
#0 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/PaymentProcessor.php(430): civicrm_api3("PaymentProcessor", "create", (Array:28))
#1 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/PaymentProcessor.php(383): CRM_Admin_Form_PaymentProcessor->updatePaymentProcessor((Array:20), 1, FALSE)
#2 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(435): CRM_Admin_Form_PaymentProcessor->postProcess()
#3 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#4 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_PaymentProcessor), "next", "Next")
#5 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_PaymentProcessor), "next")
#6 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_PaymentProcessor), "next")
#7 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#8 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(384): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#9 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(168): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(1, NULL)
#10 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/PaymentProcessor.php(117): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#11 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Admin_Page_PaymentProcessor->run((Array:3), NULL)
#12 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#13 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#14 /PATH-REDACTED/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1227): CRM_Core_Invoke::i
```

Where should I begin?

Comment: Props to Jon Goldberg for quickly sleuthing out the culprit here. It was me! I did it -- or rather, didn't do what I should have, namely upgrade the database when I updated from Civi 4.7.11 to 4.7.15. Jon gave me a link on the chat.civicrm.org town square and in under two minutes my problem was fixed. Here's that link for anyone googling a similar problem ...

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress#UpgradingCiviCRMforWordPress-4.RuntheUpgradescript

Comment: Can you post this as an answer and explain how to update database after upgrading? I think I forget to do this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade the database following my CiviCRM version update. Detailed instructions for doing this are at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress#UpgradingCiviCRMforWordPress-4.RuntheUpgradescript

Once I had completed this relatively simple process, I was finally able to add payment processors without throwing errors. And just as exciting, the System Status in the Civi admin footer finally switched from "Critical" to "OK."

Comment: Please mark this questions as being answered. Thanks.

Comment: Would love to. Not trying to be silly here, but how/where can I mark it as answered? Or was this directed to a forum moderator/admin?

Comment: It was directed to you :) There should be a tick icon to the left of this answer. Click it!